Quarkus Uber-Jar packaging without unpacking dependency jars
Building a Quarkus based webapp, I encounter the following issue:
I have dependencies managed by maven, resolved as jars.
When building a fast-jar, the dependencies are collected into the \target\quarkus-app\lib\main\ directory.
This works without issues.
When building a Uber-Jar, Quarkus unpacks the individual jars, and stores the content of all dependencies jars directly into the Uber-Jar instead.
Some of the dependencies have xml configuration files with the same name, at the same relative path relative to their original jar, which cannot be merged.
ex:
dependency1.jar!metainfo/config.xml
dependency2.jar!metainfo/config.xml
As a result, I'm getting a build warning:
[WARNING] [io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.JarResultBuildStep] Dependencies with duplicate files detected. The dependencies [redacted] contain duplicate files, e.g. metainfo/config.xml
and only one of the dependencies's file are copied into the resulting jar.
I've reviewed the solutions proposed in this question:
in Quarkus, can I merge files that have the same name in many dependencies, ie typesafe config files?
but this is not suitable here, since the config files cannot be merged into a single config.xml
I've looked for configuration switches to bundle the full jars into the resulting fat jar instead of unpacking them, but I haven't found one so far.
My goal is to create a single executable jar (fast-jar doesn't feel that role, since it needs the additional lib folder to run), but without unpacking the dependencies (which causes issues with the libraries).

There is no way currently to do what you are after
